# How to use JQuery to grab the selected option off of a class?

Tags: javascript, jquery, razor

I have a table with a bunch of rows with the same dropdown options. What I want to do is on a button click, grab the selected values for the dropdown that the row that the button is in.

```
<select class="items" data-value="@item.Id">
    <option>None</option>
    @foreach (var item in ViewBag.Items)
    {
       <!option value="@(item)">
           @(item.Title)
       </!option>
    }
</select>
```

What I have tried to do is:

```
var button = $(event.target);
var itemClass = button.closest(".items");
var selectedItem = itemClass.options[this.selectedIndex].text;
```

This does correctly grab the class, but it can't seem to get text of the selected item.

Comment: Do you want the text of the option or the value of the select?

Comment: The text is what I am going after.

Comment: You might want to try text(). I know that text (without the parenthesis) is a JS method, but it looks like you may be casting to a jQuery object (some of your code is missing). If that is the case - then text() is a function, not a method in jQuery - so you need the parenthesis.